# Displaying nothing when I am trying to scrape data using simple html dom parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Here is my code:

```
$html1 = file_get_html("https://www.amazon.com" .
    "/Tom-Clancys-Division-Xbox-One/dp/B00DDXILBQ/" .
    "ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1487430751&sr=8-1&keywords=Tom%2BClancy%27s%2BThe%2BDivision&th=1");
$title1 = $html1 - > find("div.sims-fbt-rows,0") - > find("span.p13n-sc-price") - > innertext;
if ($title1) {
    echo $title1;
} else {
    echo 'problem';
}
```

Basically, I am trying to scrap prices from amazon I have an example page here. I am trying to scrap price for it. When I load my PHP page It doesn't display anything and get an error from Wamp saying

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find () an array in
>   C:\wamp64\www\test.php on line 15

BTW, I am viewing the page source code in chrome and you can find all classes from which data is to be extracted on line 9765.

I have even tried using children and sibling function, but nothing is working.

Comment: according to the error message you are dealing with and `array`, while you are treating it as an object.

Comment: Also, the ",0" belongs outside of the quotes on that css selector.

Comment: I don't know why stackoverflow is changing my link but I tried editing the link once again back to the link what I am using. Stackoverflow changed the link once again.Any way when I went to the link which stackoverflow modified,it redirected to the page where my link take users to.

Comment: @user7587888: ah, the auto-amazon link updates.. This is a bug, I filed it as [Don't auto-replace amazon links in code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/291335)

Comment: @user7587888: the work-around is to split the string into two pieces; I've done so now.